# Is there any way to assign a shortcut to multiple commands that you need to repeat again and again? a script may be?

Tags: scripting

I am working on some objects, all of them needs same commands/functions.
Can anyone help me with something that can execute those commands step by step with one shortcut.

Comment: There are also add-ons which can record and playback what you do in Blender. Maybe you wanna search for „blender macro add-on“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can use [Blender's Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html) that lets you use [Python](https://www.python.org/) to program what happens in Blender. Explore the links - they can be extremely useful.

You can find a lot of exaples in the Text Editor's Templates menu:
[image]

You can also just see commands being executed as you use Blender's UI in the Info panel:

[image]

So the most primitive way would be to copy and paste those commands into a new text block starting with `import bpy` in the Text Editor and hit run to run some sequence of those commands, but you might want to learn more about coding for more flexibility.

[image]

If you ask more specific questions detailing specifically what you need, there are plenty of people here who will help with Python. The trick is to form your questions in a specific and clear manner.